# normal OS boot and virtual boot in windows as vhd

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, multi-boot, vhd

Is it possible to install e.g. ubuntu on a vhd in virtualbox and boot it normally at the pc start or start it as a virtual machine in Windows 8 or Win7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Windows is currently the only operating system that supports [booting directly from VHD files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/haroldwong/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-create-windows-8-vhd-for-boot-to-vhd-using-simple-easy-to-follow-steps.aspx) without the use of a hypervisor.

Your solutions for using Ubuntu are the following:

1. Install it in a virtual machine (as you've done already) and create a startup entry for VirtualBox that will load your VM file upon Windows login. [This article](http://brockangelo.com/2009/12/15/how-to-start-a-virtual-machine-at-startup-using-virtualbox/) may be of use.
2. Install Ubuntu inside Windows using [the Wubi installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer). Note this is not virtualisation.
3. Install Ubuntu natively, on its own partition, alongside Windows.